# How can I rank preferences without ranking records in a ML model?

Tags: machine-learning, ranking, auc

In a binary classification problem about the purchase of a product I use AUC to evaluate the performance of the model.

Due to some restrictions I can't assign to each record of my data set any metric or even the model's score, but I can compare two different records i.e. I can assign a score to any couple of records.

Are there general methods and/or existing ML models for reconstruct the preferences' ranking without explicitly assigning scores to each record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank

**Learning to Rank** (LTR) is a class of techniques that apply supervised machine learning (ML) to solve ranking problems. The training data for a LTR model consists of a list of items and a **“ground truth” score** for each of those items.

There are many machine learning algorithms used for ranking tasks; for example, many of them are used by search engines to rank results of a query. For search engine ranking, this translates to a list of results for a query and a relevance rating for each of those results with respect to the query.

The most famous ranking algorithms are **RankNet, LambdaRank and LambdaMART**: in all three techniques, ranking is transformed into a pairwise classification or regression problem. That means you look at pairs of items at a time, come up with the optimal ordering for that pair of items, and then use it to come up with the final ranking for all the results.
Even XG-Boost can achieve ranking tasks but literature is full of algorithms to this purpose.

In general, there are three kind of approaches, **pointwise, pairwise and listwise**. In your case , the most suitable approach seems to be the **pairwise** one. In this approach, the learning-to-rank problem is approximated by a classification problem, learning a binary classifier that can tell which document is better in a given pair of documents. The goal is to minimize the average number of inversions in ranking.

Comment: The pairwise approach seems useful, thanks en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank#Pairwise_approach

Comment: Good point, but few sentences of explanation accompanying the link would be useful.

Comment: sorry, I'm a newbie, just edited the answer